# how add two text in switch button, title and subtitle?

Tags: java, android

How can we add two text in switch button, title and subtitle as depicted in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: how come you able to identify it as a single view? seems like a PreferenceActivity https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Comment: Image from google

Comment: Here > have fun https://blog.gldraphael.com/adding-a-toolbar-to-preference-activity/ http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-tutorial-preferencescreen-preferenceactivity-preferencefragment

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have several alternatives to achieve such button view.

Alternative 1: You can design a custom view to match your need. With a custom view, you can design anything that you need.

Alternative 2: If you can set the text of the button in this way,

```
android:text="Titel \n subTitle"
```

Alternative 3: Similar to alternative 2, you can do the following.

```
button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><big>" + "Title" + "</big></b>" +  "<br />" + 
        "<small>" + "subtitle" + "</small>" + "<br />"));
```

I am not sure whether you will get exactly such button with alternative 2 and 3, but you can check. If I were in your place, I would design a custom view that means I would have followed alternative 1.

Answer (score -3):

You Should Follow this to add the text that appear on switching the button:

```
toggleButton.setText(textOff);    // Initial State
toggleButton.setTextOff(textOff) // When Switch is Checked Off
toggleButton.setTextOn(textOn);  // When Switch is Checked On
```

Associated Text (XML)

```
android:textOff="Custom Notification Disabled"
android:textOn="Custom Notification Enabled"
```

Hoping this will help to sort your issue!